# Lowest possible fps of Animated Gif on AWS Elastic Transcoder

Tags: amazon-web-services, animated-gif, transcoding, amazon-elastic-transcoder

From the AWS documentation it looks like the lowest possible fps for an animated gif is 10fps. Is there a way to have AWS create an animated gif with a lower fps?